# Application is not displayed in recent apps lists

Tags: android, android-manifest

My application is never shown in the RECENT APPS list whenever I put the following piece of code in my activity's manifest entry

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

If I remove above line it works fine. I've also made sure that the following flags are set to false-

```
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:excludeFromRecents="false"
```

But still its never displayed even if I launch app manually.

In case anybody wants to have a look the manifest, its-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:name="com.raj.poc.copypaste.MainApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".CopyPasteActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:excludeFromRecents="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity not showing in list of recent apps when launched from a widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349590/activity-not-showing-in-list-of-recent-apps-when-launched-from-a-widget)

Answer (score 24):

It may also happen if you set

```
    <activity... android:label=""/>
```

for your main `Activity`

Comment: Awesome. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @riwnodennyk Can you tell the reason for this? How does having a label makes it disappear from recents list

Answer (score 0):

This is the only activity in your application, right?

You are using the category tag twice. You have written in your code

```
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

so you have already selected the category. When you add a new activity then you will write the Default category tag.

Comment: I am sorry but I have some more activities in my application, I've just not shown it here just to make it look simple. So does it mean, we can not place two CATEGORY tags for one acitivity? Then is there a way to do so except for writing a new activity and calling this one from that activity unncessarily?

Comment: In my applications I don't use the category tag twice for each activity. I don't understand your last question. Could you please become more specific?

Comment: Ok. I want to ask, can we at all use Category tag twice for one activity? I need both LAUNCHER & DEFAULT categories for my activity. One way I can find is declare some X activity with category LAUNCHER and call another Y activity which has DEFAULT category.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know the answer. I would suggest you to talk with other android developers on IRC. Go to dev.android.com and there you will find a link to the chat room.