# Activity not showing in list of recent apps when launched from a widget

Tags: android

I have created an app widget which, when clicked, launches an Activity in my application.

The activity it launches is **NOT** the main launcher activity (as set in the application manifest).

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The activity I'm launching has launchMode="singleTop" (may be relevant)

If I launch the app from the app launcher, then press home and then the recent apps button, the app is there. 
I then remove the app from recent activities list or force close it.

If I then click on my widget, the activity launches fine.
I then press Home and then the app does not appear in the list of recent apps.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you starting the activity from the widget? What intent flags are you using? Post the manifest entry for the activity that gets launched from the widget

Comment: Uh oops - after looking at the launched Activity's definition in the Manifest, I realise it's not working cos the activity has android:excludeFromRecents="true" - not sure when i put that in there, oops. After removing this, it all works. Silly me :) Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: OK. Accept your own answer please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My activity was defined with flag `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in the Manifest.
Silly me, should've spotted that earlier.
Removing that flag fixes the problem.

Comment: Your problem is our solution -- asking about the inverse (how do I remove an activity from Recents) yielded your answer. Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: Glad my mistake could help someone ;)