# android - My app doesn't show in recent apps list

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I am working on an app and have just realised it doesn't show in the recent apps list.

I have 2 activities in the app and no matter which I am on when I hit the Home key, the app isn't shown in the recent apps list.

I have seen this question: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580988/application-is-not-displayed-in-recent-apps-lists) but putting the category stuff in the manifest hasn't worked for me.

Below is the  part of my manifest:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <service android:name=".UploadService" android:exported="false" />
    <service android:name=".DownloadService" android:exported="false" />

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:name="com.test.DOHSMain" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.test.DOHSChange"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Note:** I added the  tag on the second activity DOHSChange just in case that would help but having that line there or not seems to do nothing.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` from your manifest

Comment: Godamn what an idiot, is that a default thing in the Manifest or did I somehow copy it in?

Comment: :) ... naah, it's not there by default

Answer (score 2):

You have `android:excludeFromRecents=true` in your launcher activity.