# why android app not show in recent task?

Tags: android

I have a android demo just have one activity. Make the activity call finish() in (onCreate|onStart|onResume), then click the recent button but my activity not show in recent tasks. But when I use code like this, it shows in recent tasks.It seems that after all the life cycles go through and then it show in recent tasks? Can anyone tell me what's going on, thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getMainLooper().getQueue().addIdleHandler(new MessageQueue.IdleHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean queueIdle() {
                finish();
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

I don't use android:excludeFromRecents="true", in manifest just like this:

```
<activity android:name=".XXXActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android - My app doesn't show in recent apps list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119825/android-my-app-doesnt-show-in-recent-apps-list)

Comment: it's not duplicate of the question link you provided. The question clearly says that app shows in the recent task list with the above code but doesn't show with a normal `finish()`. it means `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @sunpointed what happens when you just call `finish()` on a button click after activity completes its lifecycle?

Comment: I guess it might be due to the fact that `finish()` posts an _exit_ request to Activities message queue too early before the system is even finished processing the app's startup and hence have no chance to get a _screenshot_ ofthe app

Comment: I think call finish() on a button click just the same as use the IdleHandler,  it will appear in recent tasks

Comment: @riyaz-ali you may be right , but when and how the android system get a screenshot of the app?

Comment: **when**: not sure but my guess is it takes the screenshot after `onResume()` and before `onPause()` as that is the documented lifecycle call after which your app is in foreground  

**how**: screenshot is taken on the system server side by querying the WindowManager system service

Comment: I use IdleHandler and I know queueIdle() method must call when mainThread wait for messages so the finish() is call after onResume(); I know you says are right， but I want to know the detail of the system about when and how put an activity(app) in recent tasks.Is there some code show this detail ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you may have set

```
<activity... android:label=""/>
```

to hide the action bar name..or you have set

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Comment: I don't set android:excludeFromRecents="true"