# Application is not shown in Recent Apps list when opened via PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-recents

My app offers a widget. User can add the widget to the home screen of his Android OS. When the user taps the widget my app gets opened.

The issue is: when run so, the app is not shown in the Recent Apps list.

How can I make my app to shown in the Recent Apps list regardless of how it was opened?

Here is the intent used to open the app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_contents, pendingIntent);
```

Here is the declaration of the activity in the app's manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_browse_playlist"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580988/application-is-not-displayed-in-recent-apps-lists, maybe that helped you

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan unfortunately, it didn't helped.