# Is there an issue in Android? How it affects my app to be invisible?

Tags: android

If I did not give the label name for my launcher activity, then my app is not visible in recent apps.

```
android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
<string name="title_activity_login"></string>
```

It is like a textbox without label. I don't think it is a big problem.

**How it affects my app to be invisible?**

Comment: You call this an issue?

Comment: What is your question, exactly? I don't understand what "How it affects my app to invisible?" means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application is not displayed in recent apps lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580988/application-is-not-displayed-in-recent-apps-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label attribute in an activity element `is displayed on-screen when the activity must be represented to the user.` You can also notice that the launcher activity's label is used to be displayed as the app name in the list of applications. If you don't supply a label, the package name is used instead. I guess that if you supply an invalid name, like an empty string, it all fails and the app in the apps list has no name and it doesn't show up in the recents screen.

[This is quite old btw.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580988/application-is-not-displayed-in-recent-apps-lists)